# How does a texture image file get mapped on an OBJ model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, objects, image

I am trying to understand how a texture image is mapped on an OBJ file. For example, if you map below color grid image (texture) on the capsule obj model (screenshot #1), it looks like the screenshot #2.

QUESTION:
How do we know where the first pixel on the top left corner of the texture file will stay on the OBJ model surface? Does the OBJ file carry such a data? Or are there certain rules/protocols about texture mapping? Or does Blender have internal logic? I'd like to know the fundamental principle of texture mapping. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
Grid Image (texture)

[image]
Screenshot #1

[image]
Screenshot #2

Model source: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/minobj.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because the capsule object already has a UV Map, as shown in the image below.
The OBJ file format keeps the UV coordinates, which are assigned during unwrapping of your model in the UV space.

[image: capsuleuvs]

The answer to *"How do we know where the first pixel on the top left corner of the texture file will stay on the OBJ model surface?"* is **unwrapping**. Basically, when you unwrap your model, you unfold it so you can have a 2D projection of it. A simple object like the capsule is fairly simple to unwrap to a single part. But if you have a more complex object (such as *Suzanne*), you have to separate your mesh in several parts by creating *Seams*, and unfold one part at a time, to get a result like this:

[image: suzanneuvs]

This procedure is fundamental to apply textures on your model: any other texture will be applied based on the UV map coordinates that you have created. My suggestion is to use a *checker color grid* while you unwrap your model, so you can have a nice preview of how the textures will be applied on your model:

[image: checkercreation]

[image: checker]

Keep in mind this concept: any other texture will be applied in the **same exact way** the color grid is applied. You have to take control of the distortions: it's normal to have some distortion while unwrapping your model (because you convert your model from 3D to 2D). Adding seams reduce a lot the distortions on your unwrap. Anyway, common mistakes at the beginning are:

- stretched and/or squashed uvs (**first image below**)
- not uniform scale of the projections (**second image below**)

[image: squash]
[image: scale]

The model is correctly unwrapped when you see perfect squared numbers of the color grid texture over all the parts of your model.

Useful resources:

- [Darrin Lile - Basics of UV Map](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2-FfB9kRmE&list=PLyelx0TsmSpdSoVNlkGo7LAk3mhfxbMhd)
- [Darrin Lile - Character UV Map](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-ZmDKuB6HI&list=PLyelx0TsmSpdQwcx1OloZuW48bOUJQ02s)

Comment: Thanks so much, @G. Garone. Beautifully explained!! I have another question—do other file formats such as gltf, fbx, and dae contain UV mapping data in the models?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, FBX, GLTF, OBJ and DAE keep UV mapping data. PLY file format too, but sometimes getting this information is a bit more tricky. However this format is mostly used in 3D scanning context.